# Passing PathVariable to AJAX controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I want to be able to pass the value entered in the textbox, on a mouse click, to my AJAX controller.

Controller code:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Controller
public class HelloWorldController {

    public static class User {

        private String name, surname;
        int age;

        public User(String name, String surname, int age) {
            this.name = name;
            this.surname = surname;
            this.age = age;
        }

        public int getAge() {
            return age;
        }

        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }

        public String getSurname() {
            return surname;
        }
    }

    @RequestMapping("/hello")
    public ModelAndView helloWorld() {
        return new ModelAndView("home/hello.jsp", "message", "Spring MVC Demo");
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello/{name}", produces = "application/json")
    public @ResponseBody User getUser(@PathVariable(value = "name") String name) {
        return new User(name, "Surname", 25);
    }
}
```

Relevant view code:

```
        $.getJSON("hello/", {name: $('#username').val()} , function(obj) {
                            $("ul").append("<li>"+obj.name+"</li>");
                        });

// ...

    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" >
```

So this doesn't work, when the button is clicked, nothing happens. However, when I change in my controller to `@RequestParam` it works, but I want it to work with `@PathVariable` so that the URL for the correct `username` gets displayed.

Where is the problem, how should I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like that because you're using GET method to pass your HTTP request the parameter (name) is passed via a query string.

That's why `@RequestParam` works and `@PathVariable` doesn't.

If you must do it with GET method then try to build your URL as follows:

```
/hello/" + $('#username').val() + "/"
```

**and don't pass data with your ajax request**.

Try to work with firebug or google developer tools in order to see what data is going to server and back to browser.

something like that:

```
$.getJSON(/hello/" + $('#username').val() + "/", 
    function(obj) {
         $("ul").append("<li>"+obj.name+"</li>");
});
```

Comment: _"and don't pass data with your ajax request"_ What do you mean by that?

Comment: it means don't use data: in your jquery ajax call. in your case don't pass {name: $('#username').val()}